# multiprocessing and python code

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

the execution of my python code is too slow, I have 7 processors and python uses only one, I just discovered the multiprocessing option but I have no idea how to use it, so could you modify my following code using this option?

```
from itertools import combinations

def New5(A,C5):
    d=True
    for a in A:
        if(d==True):
            d=(a not in C5)
    return d

def refcomb10(h):
    T=[]
    C5={0}
    b=0
    C10=combinations(range(h),10)
    for S in C10:
        A=combinations(S,5)
        if(New5(A,C5)):
            A=combinations(S,5)
            for a in A:
                C5.update({a})
            T.append(S)
            b+=1
            print(b,S)
    return([T,C5])

U=refcomb10(60)
```

Excuse my english

Comment: This should move to the [code-review](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) group.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what this function is doing? Because it looks really horrendously inefficient (your example is iterating through `C(100, 10) * C(10, 5)` equals just over 4.3 quadrillion possibilities).

Comment: ... at a million combinations per second, it will take about 138 years to finish. *Finding a better algorithm* is almost certainly better than *crunching faster*.

Comment: @HughBothwell  what I'm trying to do is to get all combinations C(X,10) that doesn't have combinations C(X,5) in common, for example:  these combinations: (1,2,3) (1,4,5) (1,6,7) (2,4,7) (2,5,6) (3,4,6) (3,5,7) are C(7,3) where every C(7,2) = ((1,2)(1,3)(1,4).....) appear only once

Comment: @HughBothwell   I modified the code in the question, I posted the entire code, I wish you have an alternative

Comment: I am still looking for a Python solution; you might find http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193917/minimally-intersecting-subsets-of-fixed-size of interest - you should apparently "take the the indicator functions of the hyperplanes of the 3-dimensional affine space over F2". Now I am just trying to figure out what that means ;-)

Comment: Do you need *all combinations*, or *any* combination that meets this criteria? (I guess a related question would be, how many families of combinations are there which are not equivalent after renumbering/reordering?)

Comment: Regardless of good algorithms and parallization, I'm always a bit stunned at people that want to write *parallel* Python code.   Python is an *interpreter*; interpreters typically pay 10-100x performance loss over native assembler or well-compiled C/C++ code.  If you want your answer finished soonest a) always pick as efficient an algorithm as you can, b) compile it to run using the machine's instruction set.   If that doesn't get you enough, *then* parallelization starts to make sense. (If you are doing to just a learning exercise, than that's OK, just understand this isn't the right way).

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to multithread to fix your performance problem. These improvements may be more helpful:

- remove `print(b,S)`
- remove the second `A=combinations(S,5)`, if possible
- replace

  ```
   for a in A:
       C5.append(a)
  ```

  with

  ```
   C5.extend(A)
  ```
- profile your code, perhaps like this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html. Find what function is slow and try to make it faster.

Comment: I think these changes won't make difference because the condition "if ........ :" is rarely satisfied, I modified the question and put the entire code, wish you have a solution @BrianMalehorn

Comment: Ah, you're right. Your real problem is this: `combinations(range(h),10)`. 60 choose 10 = 75,394,027,566. There are 75 billion things in this list, that's way too many to iterate over (python can iterate over about 1 million things / second).